# Why causes stochastic processes to not repeat their samples of elements that do not depend on time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, definition

Suppose that we have a stochastic process of the form $X_t=t\cdot Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Anyone who has ever done a course in stochastic processes will be able to tell you that the realizations of this process will only differ due to the value of $t$ increasing. For example, we will always have $2X_1=X_2$. Similarly, we can see that the distribution $Z$ is only ever sampled once in any realization of the entire stochastic process.

My question is as follows - why is $Z$ only sampled once? I can understand the practical reasons for it, but what **specific definition** is responsible for this? It's certainly not part of any definitions of *random variable* or *stochastic process* that I've ever seen.

Comment: Can you quote the textbook and the page where you have found this definition?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins What definition? I haven't given any.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. I am a bit surprised that the random variable is not resampled for every time step. I was wondering if you could give a link to anything that claims that the random variable should not be resampled

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I most often see it come up in exercises from stochastic processes books, rather than mentioned explicitly in their text. For example, proving whether or not something is a Brownian motion.

Comment: I find that strange. Brownian motion requires that successive random numbers are i.i.d, that's more or less the definition. No clue how one would prove that if the numbers are rescaled versions of each other. But don't take my word for it, hopefully an expert in the field can be more useful :)

Comment: Let $\omega$ be an element of a sample space (for $X_t$), then a sample path of a stochastic process is $\{X_t(\omega) \colon t \geq 0\}$. So in your case one sample path is (for a fixed $\omega$ from a sample space) the following set $\{ tZ(\omega) \colon t \geq 0\}$. Your $X_t$ is different than $Y_t = t Z_t$, where $Z_t$ is a family of independent standard normal random variables.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @m_gnacik Yes, it does. Although that still doesn't answer which definition is the cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on the definition of a stochastic process, in particular, the corresponding probability space makes a big contribution; it is not often even mentioned as people find it either obvious (after you do a course in measure theory) or they rely on their intuition (less rigorous approach often without measure theory background).

I will try to explain it on a very simple example that is a bit similar to the one you mentioned, I will just use discrete time processes and also instead a normal random variable I will use a Bernoulli one.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be as follows $\Omega = \{Heads, Tails\}$, $\mathcal{F} = 2^{\Omega}$ and $\mathbb{P} \colon \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be defined as $\mathbb{P}(\{Heads\}) =  \mathbb{P}(\{Tails\}) = 0.5$. Define a random variable $Z \colon \Omega \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$  such that $Z(Heads) = 1$, $Z(Tails)= -1$. Clearly, $Z$ is a Bernoulli (or Radomacher depending on nomenclature) random variable, in particular its distribution is given by $\mathbb{P}(Z=1) = \mathbb{P}(Z=-1) =0.5$.
Let us construct a discrete stochastic process $X=(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $X_n = n Z$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For any $n$, $nZ$ is random variable on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. We have clearly only two sample paths (realisations) of this process that is, for $\omega = Heads$ we have $\{n  \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$  and for $\omega = Tails$ we have $\{-n \  \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Now, let us consider a different process, and let $Y$ be an independent copy of $Z$, that is $Y$ has the same distribution as $Z$ and they are both independent. 
We define a stochastic process $X=(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the probability space will be $( \Omega \times \Omega, 2^{\Omega \times \Omega}, \mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P})$
as follows 
$$X_n = \begin{cases}nY &\mbox{ if } n  \mbox{ is odd} \\ nZ &  \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is even } \end{cases}.$$ 
In particular, for the above definition to make sense, for any $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \Omega \times \Omega$  we identify $Z(\omega) \equiv Z(\omega_1)$ and $Y(\omega) \equiv Y(\omega_2)$; so that each $X_n$ are defined on the same probability space.

Therefore, we have four paths in total, for $\omega = (Heads, Heads)$ we have $\{ n  \colon \mbox{ odd}\} \cup \{ n \colon n \mbox{ even}\} = \mathbb{N}$, for $\omega = (Tails, Heads) $ we have $\{ -n  \colon n \mbox{ even} \} \cup \{ n \colon n \mbox{ odd}\}$ and so on for the other choices from $\Omega \times \Omega$.

So your sampling depends on the definition of a stochastic process itself; what is the underlying probability space, and how you identify your random variables. I hope that I was clear enough.